# Highcharts with Variable Data

Tags: javascript, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to use Highcharts with Django--but I'm not at all familiar with Javascript.

I'm charting emissions inventories for different colleges. A user will select the colleges they want to display, so the amount of data being returned will vary.

I've converted each Django variable into a Javascript variable so they can be accessed:

```
{% for college in collegelist %}
    <script>
    function removeCommas(str) {
        return(str.replace(/,/g,''));
    }
    collegearray[collegecounter] = [parseInt(removeCommas("{{ college.stationarycombustion }}")), parseInt(removeCommas("{{ college.mobilecombustion }}")), parseInt(removeCommas("{{ college.processemissions }}")), parseInt(removeCommas("{{ college.fugitiveemissions }}")), parseInt(removeCommas("{{ college.scope1 }}")) ];
    collegecounter++;
    </script>
{% endfor %}
```

So as you can see, the collegearray contains arrays that contain all of the data for a college (Stationary Combustion, Mobile Combustion, etc).

Then the Highcharts Javascript function contains assignments like this:

```
series: [{
            name: 'College 1',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0]

        }, {
            name: 'College 2',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0]

        },
```

But, since the amount of data to be charted will vary, essentially what I'd like to be able to write is the equivalent of:

```
counter = 0
for college in collegelist:
    name: collegename[counter],
    data: collegearray[counter]
    counter += 1
```

However, Javascript keeps complaining that I can't use a for loop to handle assignments this way. Is there a way to break out of Javascript, use Django's templating conditionals {% for college in college list %}, and assign the output back into the Javascript function? Or some other way? Am I making this more difficult than it needs to be?

Thanks for any advice,
Brett

Per request, the model:
I should note that I'm not using Django-Chartit, so I'm not building the charts directly from the models.

```
class Inventories(models.Model):
    institution = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publicationdate = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    stationarycombustion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobilecombustion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    processemissions = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fugitiveemissions = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    scope1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    purchasedelectricity = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    purchasedheating = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    purchasedcooling = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    purchasedsteam = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    scope2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    commuting = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    airtravel = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    solidwaste = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    wastewater = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    paperemissions = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    scope2td = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    scope3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    carbonoffsets = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    totalrecs = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    landsequestration = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    compostsequestration = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gsf = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    residentialspace = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    studentfte = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.institution+", "+self.publicationdate
```

Comment: I'm using Highcharts in my website and it's not difficult to forloop objects inside the script. It just like for looping in the template. Can you post your models codes that you want to show in the chart

Comment: Happy to. I mentioned above, in case it's relevant, I'm not using Django-Chartit, so I'm not charting directly from the models.

Comment: I try to use Django-Chartit with Highcharts but I can't make it work so I end up only using Highcharts

Comment: which of the fields do you want to show in your chart?

Comment: Catherine--you're great. Thanks for the help. I actually just solved this one; I'll post an answer here in a moment.

Comment: Ok, I'm too new to answer my own question right now. But I will when the time limit is up.

Comment: That's nice, you figure it out!