# Highchart not able to use javascript variables(arrays) in series data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi I am trying to use array variables in highchart series data but i am not getting the values in the chart(the line is not ploted).

```
var day = [];
        var count = [];
        var i = 0; 
        var j = 0;
        $.each(data.day,function(index,value){
        day[i++] = value;
        });
        $.each(data.count,function(index,value){
        count[j++] = value;
        });


series: [{
            name: 'Profile View',
            data: [count[0],count[1],count[2],count[3],count[4],count[5],count[6]] 
        }]
```

i am not getting the values of either of count or day here 
    while it is working fine for the categories

```
xAxis: {

                categories: [day[0], day[1], day[2], day[3], day[4], day[5],count[6]]
            }
```

I have been stuck here for quite a time but can't figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a small change in your code,it might work

```
series: [{
                name: 'Profile View',
                data: JSON.parse("[" + count + "]") 
            }]
```

[Highcharts with Variable Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725265/highcharts-with-variable-data)